# React module logs perfectly on console, but does not show on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I am having a strange problem with the code below.

After mapping the notes, `{notes.map(note => { ...}); console.log({notes})` returns an array of four items. There are four items in the array. Similarly, `console.log({note.title})` logs each item's title as a map method would. When we call `{note.title}` on the line before `console.log({note.title})`, nothing appears on the page!!! An example of the code is shown below in a summarized form. The code with the problem has been pushed to the GitHub. You can see it under the commit "MyNotes.js not rendering the data on-screen while it logs them perfectly on the console".

The dev-tool console logs this **error**

> Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at MyNotes.js:31.

https://github.com/bdarab/notezipper-mern

```
{
  notes.map((note) => {
    <Card style={{ margin: 10 }}>
      <Card.Header style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <span
          style={{
            alignSelf: 'center',
            color: 'black',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            flex: 1,
            fontSize: 18,
            textDecoration: 'none',
          }}
        >
          {note.title} // Doesn’t work console.log(note); // Works perfectly
        </span>

        <div>
          <Button>Edit</Button>

          <Button className='mx-2' variant='danger'>
            {' '}
            Delete{' '}
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Card.Header>
    </Card>;
  });
}
```

The strange thing is that everything works when I console.log() them, but it doesn't appear on the page. I continued coding blindly. Now, I have methods of showing {note._id}, {note.category}, and {note.content}that work perfectly when I log them on the console. In real code, though, I get no results. Why? https://github.com/bdarab/notezipper-mern

Comment: The source you linked doesn't show the code you've included in the question. The Github code for `MyNotes.js` is using `notes.forEach`, not `notes.map`. `forEach` doesn't return anything, so you would expect nothing to reach the page, while `map` returns an array and you would expect results. Are you sure you're using `map`?

Answer (score 1):

add a return statement.

return <Card style={{ margin: 10 }}>

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, everyone!  Problem solved. it was a react-bootstrap problem. Using codes of 1.6 version while npm had installed the newer 2.0 version. thanks for your interest.